# C++ linked lists Remove and RemoveBack function

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was wondering how to create a linked list with a remove(int num) and removeback(int num)? using the same format as provided in prepend?

```
#include "ll.h"

LL::LL()
{
head = NULL;
}

void LL::prepend(int num)
{
node* newNode = new node;
newNode->val = val;
newNode->next = NULL;

if (head == NULL)
{
    head = newNode;
}
else
{
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
    newNode = NULL;
}

}

void LL::remove(int num)
{

}

void LL:removeBack (int num)
{


}
```

I think remove and removeBack would be the same function? Correct? Also how do I pass that value back

Comment: Are you asking how to write the functions? What do you mean by "same format"?

Comment: It's odd to pass a parameter to `removeBack`, and your class definition suggests that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that remove(int num) removes the first node that has the same value as num. I'll leave removeBack as an exercise for you :).

```
void LL:remove(int num) {
    if (!head) {
        return;
    }
    else if (head->val == num) {
        node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        return;
    }

    node* second = head;
    node* first = head->next;

    // Iterate until we find the target, or reach the end
    while (first && first->val != num) {
        second = first;
        first = first->next;
    }

    // At this point, first points to either nullptr or the target
    if (first) {
        second->next = first->next;
        delete first;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about searching for the node and then deleting the node with that value?

```
void LL:remove (int num){
ListNode *nodePtr, *previousNode;
if (!head) {
    return;
}
else if (head->value == num)
{
   nodePtr = head->next;
   delete head;
   head = nodePtr;
 }
 else
 {
 nodePtr=head;
     while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value !=num){
     previousNode = nodePtr;
     nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
     }
 previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
 delete nodePtr;
 }
```

}